# How to retrieve the group SID from GroupName by C++

Tags: c++, msdn

I have knew the administrator Group sid(Well-know-sid) is "S-1-5-32-544", but I research the msdn, I don't find any way can retrieve the Group sid by groupName.

I use ::NetLocalGroupEnum to list all groupName. Moreover, I want to know which group is administrator Group. Administrator Group's name is "administrator" by default. If someone modifies Administrator Group's name(ex: from "administrator" to "123" ), how can I know the "123" is belong to administrator Group. Now I use String to determine which group is Administrator Group, but if Group Name is modified, this way is not work. I also use ::NetLocalGroupGetInfo, but it's output structure only include name and comment but not group SID. Is any API or way is about input is the groupName, and OutPut is Group sid? Thanks!

Comment: Can we use dot net framework?

Comment: @YasharAliabasi  my environment just c++....but you can use it to try!

Comment: So only way is Win API? @fadder

Comment: @YasharAliabasi, I think so@@

Comment: Did you try WMIC queries? @fadder

Comment: @YasharAliabasi hm.. not yet, I tring!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `LookupAccountSid()` on your "S-1-5-32-544" SID. You'll get back a name with type `SidTypeGroup`.

As you correctly noted, the SID values are well-known (stable), so you use those as input. Account names can be localized, so those are the output.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with PowerShell and found following information I hope this helps:

1. [Adding ActiveDirectory Module to PS](https://superuser.com/questions/867467/how-to-add-active-directory-module-in-powershell-in-windows-8)
2. run `Get-ADGroup -Identity Administrators` that `Administrators` is the name of your group
   [image]

Comment: Please put the WMIC commands in the answer instead of linking to them